# Position jquery progress bar in middle of of page

Tags: jquery, css

How do i position jquery progress bar in middle of of page even though the page might be scrolled down?

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>

 $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: false
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean fixed in the center of the viewport like in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GYjr/)**

You need to make the progress bar's `position: fixed;` , position it 50% from the top and 50% from the left. Then you need to offset it by half of it's width/height using a negative `margin-left` and negative `margin-top`

This is what it would look like if the progress bar was `500px` wide and `20px` tall:

```
#progress {
    width: 500px;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -10px 0 0 -250px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Declare `#progressbar`'s `position` as `fixed`. `fixed` elements always refer to the  browser window.

```
<style>
  #progressbar { position:fixed; top: 50%; left:50%; }
</Style>
```